# Detect touch on UIView with Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

How can I detect touches in a `UIviewController` for a `UIView` with code only (without Interface Builder)?

I found the touchesBegan method but it doesn't get called ever. I didn't initialize anything else regarding this method.

```m
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: touchesBegan is part  of UIView, and you must have touches enabled, in order to get touches to the viewcontroller you should probably have the view tell the c ontroller of touches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#import "TouchView.h"


//TouchView.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TouchViewDelegate.h"

@interface TouchView : UIView {
    id <TouchViewDelegate>  delegate;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
@end

//TouchView.m

@implementation TouchView
@synthesize delegate;

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return self;
}
-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [delegate touchDown:self];
}
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [delegate touchUp:self];
}
@end

//TouchViewDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol TouchViewDelegate
-(void) touchDown:(id) sender;
-(void) touchUp:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: Hello @madmik3. Good snippet, but how can I assign the delegate?

Comment: The property should use "assign" not retain.
To set the delegate
TouchView *tv = ....;
tv.delegate = self;
...

Answer (score 1):

I would read over the [Touch Events sections](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW15) of the iPhone Application Programming Guide.

[UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) and [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) are both [UIResponders](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder), which is responsible for handling the events.

To handle events, you need to override the touch* methods to do what you want. To know what kind of touch events occurred, look at the [UIEvent](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIEvent).

Answer (score 0):

In your init method:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction for madmik3,

you're missing the super call in your initWithFrame.

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
 if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
 self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 }  return self;
}
```