# how to make my image clickable

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Obviously I missunderstood UIImageView vs UIImage, in order to register gesture(such as tap/click) on image, i need to have  image in uiimageview and register gesture on uiimageview not on uiimage.

So this piece of code works for me :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
    Obj *obj = ... obj has imageHref which is NSString

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:obj.imageHref]]; 
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.with/2), (self.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2), image.size.width, image.size.height)];

}
```

This gives me the centered image, but useless because I want it to be clickable so I though just do it with UIImageview instead like this :

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
            Obj *obj = ... obj has imageHref which is NSString

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:obj.imageHref]]; 

    CGRect rect1=CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.width/2), (self.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2), image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:radioStationImage];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];

    [backgroundImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

            [backgroundImageView drawRect:rect1];

        }
```

I just want to make this image clickable to do some kind of action when clicked, how hard can this be?

**EDIT :**

I'm actually implementing :

https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS/tree/master/ATPagingView

Which offers neat page scroll. But with clickable images in the middle of screen not page 1, 2 etc ..

EDIT 2 :

Any perspective on this today?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need custom drawing (`drawRect:`) for this. Just add the `UIImageView` as a subview when you load the view (in Interface Builder or in `loadView` depending on how you're initializing your view). You can then add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that view as you're doing.

As @jackslash notes, you also need to turn on user interaction for the image view once you've done that.

---

I believe you're making this much more complex than it is. There is no need for custom drawing with `drawRect:`. There is no need for subclassing `UIImageView` (the link @madmik3 references is not relevant to iOS4+). There probably is no need for an actual `UIView` subclass (you can do all of this inside the view controller), but here's how you would do it in a view subclass:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    Obj *obj = ... obj has imageHref which is NSString
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:obj.imageHref]]; 
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2) - (image.size.with/2), (self.frame.size.height / 2) - (image.size.height / 2), image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    [self addSubview:imageView];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Comment: I updated question maybe that can help you where I'm asking from

Comment: you fan also override the UIImageView like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848040/detect-touch-on-uiview-with-interface-builder/4494304#4494304

Comment: @madmik3 is all this necessary just to center image and to make it clickable(wow). and I was optimistic about learning iOS ..

Answer (score 2):

By default `UIImageView` has its property `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`.

do:

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: I updated question maybe that can help you where I'm asking from